# I am trying to connect Faye with Redis, client closed error

Tags: node.js, redis, faye

I have installed all extensions, client closed error persists

```
const faye = require('faye');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fayeRedis = require('faye-redis');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var shards = [
    {
        shardName: 'redis-1', // unique shard name used for consistent hashing -- if not supplied, will default to "host + ':' + port"
        host: 'localhost', // required
        port: 6379 // requiredrue
    }
];
var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({
    mount: '/faye',
    engine:  {
       type:   fayeRedis,
       shards: shards
     },
    ping: 2,
    timeout: 20
})
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "10mb",
    extended: true
}));
var channel='/channel'
app.use('', router);
const server = http.createServer(app);
bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8082);
router.post('/message', function(req,res){
    try {
        bayeux.getClient().publish('/channel',"hello");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("we got exception", err);
    }
    console.log("published message");
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
router.get("/client",(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client.html'))
})
router.get('/health', (req, res) => {
    console.log("getting response");
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
console.log("hello world!");
```

**the debug screen**

> hello world!
> /Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:409
> return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
> ^

ClientClosedError: The client is closed
at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:409:31)
at Commander.SELECT (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:209:99)
at new Engine (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye-redis/faye-redis.js:27:15)
at Function.Engine.create (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye-redis/faye-redis.js:45:10)
at klass.initialize (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye/src/engines/proxy.js:26:35)
at new klass (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye/src/util/class.js:13:28)
at Function.get (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye/src/engines/proxy.js:111:12)
at klass.initialize (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye/src/protocol/server.js:20:29)
at new klass (/Users/prashant/Downloads/node_modules/faye/src/util/class.js:13:28)
at Function.Server.create

I have tried searching in other forums, couldn't find a proper solution.
Thanks in advance for the solution